# Clock Ticks in android phone

Tags: android, android-service, system-clock

We are working on a distributed system database syncing, which relies on the real time.

As the device's time can be changed by the user or a faulty network, it can corrupt the whole database very easily. So we decided to get the time from the Master server, store it, and calculate the real time by calculating the time interval passed by counting the number of clock ticks. 
How can we get access to the hardware's clock ticks. And will we have to run some service for this? We want the ticks to be counted even while the device is on stand by/sleep/switched off. Like the actual clock displayed.
We want to it to be a sort of a parallel clock, just that only the Master server will be able to set time on it.

Comment: If you don't trust device time, why not just get server time?
Why would you create a second clock on device which works on calculation with external server?
And base syncing on that created clock?
Just sync based on your server clock.

Comment: @timmied We are creating this for remote areas and villages, network is not available all the time. So server clock is not available at all times. And the user can make an edit to the Database even while there is no connection, so that once the n/w is avaliable we can express the changes as appropriate using the time values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can we get access to the hardware's clock ticks.

You don't.

> We want the ticks to be counted even while the device is on stand by/sleep/switched off.

Your users do not. Your users want their devices to behave normally, rather than having some software keeping the CPU powered on and tying up RAM, just watching the clock tick, because that will drain the battery fairly quickly.

Perhaps things are different in "remote areas and villages" near you. In most of the known portions of the universe, time elapses even if your app is not running.

Hence, you do not need to "count ticks" to determine if time elapses. Instead, when you "get the time from the Master server" and "store it", you *also* store the current value of `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, which is the number of milliseconds since the phone was last rebooted. Then, when you need to determine the time relative to "the Master server", you compute the difference between the stored `elapsedRealtime()` value and the current `elapsedRealtime()` value, and add that number of milliseconds to the "time from the Master server" to get the current time as seen by "the master Server".

Comment: Although you did partially give me the answer, but the explanation was terrible. A link to this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html would have been better! 
with explicit markers on ACTION_TIME_CHANGED & ACTION_TIME_TICK & both the methods that you mentioned! 

Any way, still, Thank you. I will mark this question as answered!